# The convergence of the sequence $x_{n+1}= \frac{n}{n+1} x_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I wanted to examine the convergence of the series $$\displaystyle x_{n+1}= \frac{n}{n+1} x_n$$ and try to find its limit, but I'm having difficulty doing so.  The only test I thought would be useful (ratio test) was inconclusive and I'm having trouble proving $0 \leq x_n \leq 1$ that I think could help end up with a geometric sequence.  Any suggestions are welcome.

$x_1 = 1$
(This is $\forall n \geq 1$)

Comment: Try finding the first few values $x_n$ takes, and try to spot the pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little effort in filling the dots, you will see the following:

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1} x_n = \frac{n}{n+1}\frac{n-1}{n}x_{n-1} = \cdots = \frac{x_1}{n+1} = \frac1{n+1}$$

Comment: oh I got $\frac {2}{n+1}$ a little while ago, but I was convinced that was useless. Thanks

Comment: I suppose its limit is 0.

Comment: Yes sir. It is $0$.

Comment: It doesn't converge though...

Comment: @Casquibaldo: $\frac{2}{n+1}$ converges to 0. (Unless you are talking about the series $\sum \frac{2}{n+1}$, which is completely different.)

Comment: @Casquibaldo: The sequence converges, but the series does not converge. It is the harmonic series $H_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$. You can see a proof of it at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250574/what-determines-if-a-series-does-not-tend-to-0-quickly-enough

Comment: yes, I meant that the series did not converge, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're given a sequence such that

$$x_1=1$$

$$x_{n+1}=\frac n {n+1} x_n$$

Define $$u_n=nx_n$$

Then the sequence becomes

$$u_1=1\cdot x_1=1$$

$$u_{n+1}=u_n$$

It follows that $u_n=1$ for all $n$, so that

$$x_n=\frac 1 n $$

for each $n$. The limit of this series is, in turn, $0$.